# Как подключиться к nginx по локальной сети?

Tags: nginx

На компьютере в локальной сети работает nginx. Компьютер работает под windows. И если использовать Localhost как адрес подключения, то все работает хорошо.
Но как подключиться к нему по локальной сети?

```
   server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  192.168.80.131;

    root /www/;

    location /tiles/ {
        root www;
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        root   www;
        allow all;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

В качестве server_name указал ip компьютера. Но при попытке подключиться получаю 404.

До этого не работал с nginx. И может я просто файлы сайта не туда положил? Я создал папку www в корне сервера. И данные положил туда. root указал www.
Что я упустил?

Добился того что бы сайт был доступен по адресу helloworld.com

```
server{
    listen *:80;
    server_name helloworld.com www.helloworld.com;
    root D:/dev/nginx-1.12.1/www/helloworld.com;
    index index.html;
}
```

В hosts добавил запись 127.0.0.1        helloworld.com

Но с других компьютеров сети доступа нет. Ну и понятно локальный ip потому что прописал. Но если пишу туда 192.168.80.131 то ничего не происходит.

Вот xammp запускаю, то он доступен и на localhost и 127.0.0.1 и на 192.168.80.131. Почему nginx то игнорирует мой ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если видите 404 - значит, ответил nginx, значит, вы до него достучались. У вас ошибки в конфигурации. Вот пример рабочей конфигурации nginx на локальной машине:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root   /www;
        index index.php;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files       $uri = 404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include         fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

С этими настройками я обращаюсь к `localhost/info.php` и `192.168.0.xxx/info.php` и получаю один и тот же результат.

Все, что связано, с php, можете выкинуть, если вам не надо.

Comment: Я тут обманул немного. Я вижу не 404 а просто пустой экран. Т.е. как понимаю до сервера я не достучался.

Comment: Не факт, может и 500 быть, например. Смотрите код во вкладке Network консоли браузера

Comment: И да, если бы не попали на Nginx, то ответ был бы - превышено время ожидания. Хром сам пишет. Пустой экран - веб сервер ответил, но есть ошибка.

Comment: Я добился того что бы на локальном компьютере сайт был доступен по адресу helloworld.com. В host добавил запись 127.0.0.1        helloworld.com. Но с других компьютеров из сети сайт не доступен.

Comment: не знаю, что у вас с сетью. В примере - моя рабочая конфигурация на Windows 10. Сайт виден по адресу 192.168.101.xxx с Андроида по wifi.

Comment: Оказалось, что на компьютере закрыт 80 порт. Может и не закрыт, не силен в сетях. Но по меня порт на 137 сайт стал доступен в сети.

Answer (score 1):

У компьютера должно быть имя в сети. Например, какое-нибудь `WS-USER1`. Это имя должно быть доступно со всех компьютеров внутри сети. Пропишите это имя в `server_name` и обращайтесь к сайту через http://ws-user1/

Или можно убрать `server_name` вообще, а вместо `listen 80;` написать `listen 192.168.80.131:80` и обращаться к сайту через http://192.168.80.131/

Answer (score 1):

Такую же проблему решал. Симптомы те же, оказалось касперский виновен